# Integration issue in Zxing library

Tags: android, zxing

I am getting the following error while building APK after inclusion of zxing dependency.

```
Warning:com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraManager: can't find referenced method 'void setFocus(android.hardware.Camera$Parameters,com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraSettings$FocusMode,boolean)' in program class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraConfigurationUtils
```

This is my app level build.zxigradle file dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Not sure but try this compile('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }   .In manifest  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... >

Comment: Not sure, Try with other device

Comment: It seems it's a warning not an error.

Answer (score 0):

As Described in this [Class .](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java)

There is a **setFocus** Method. So I'd recommend you to please check whether it is present or not in your lib.

If it is present than keep in mind that , this method has Four parameters. So are you passing all four of them or not ?

```
public static void setFocus(Camera.Parameters parameters,
                              boolean autoFocus,
                              boolean disableContinuous,
                              boolean safeMode)
```